# How to get Bluetooth device name on BT version below 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, mfi

I am trying to fetch car bluetooth device name with BT version below 4.2 in iOS, the car panel has android OS v10. I am able to fetch the bluetooth device name above BT v4.2 but when I try below this version it gives me null.

I've tried to fetch the names using:

```
advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"] 
peripheral.name
```

Screenshot attached below for the response I am getting.

[Response when printed peripheral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0vcv.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "below 4.2 in iOS?" (your title says "below 4.0," which would be a massive difference; which do you mean?) Do you mean iPhones prior to iPhone 7? What exact versions (or devices) see the name vs don't see the name? Do you know what the device is actually sending in its advertising packet? When you say "fetch," do you mean you've connected, or you are only looking at advertising? (During connection you'll receive more information than you get from advertising packets.)

Comment: @RobNapier I've no issues with iOS versions. The issue is with the normal Bluetooth version. My code can't fetch the names of normal bluetooth version below 4.2 i.e  Android, iPhone, Watches, Android TV, Car Android Penal.

Comment: What device are you using that has a Bluetooth version below 4.2? Your list of devices after "i.e." mostly have Bluetooth 4.2 and 5.0. Only iPhones older than iPhone 7 have Bluetooth older than 4.2. (Bluetooth version has nothing to do with iOS version; it has to do with iPhone hardware.) To help you we need to know what specific devices you're having trouble with, and why you believe those devices are advertising their names (not all devices do).

Comment: Not all devices advertise their name and this might be the case here. Can you try to scan using a third party app such as nRF Connect?